# HTML: 'Float' td on top of span?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following..

**TD CSS**

```
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
border-bottom-color: #999;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-left-color: #999;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #999;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: #CCC;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
color: black;
display: table-cell;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 30px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 459px;
```

**TDHTML**

```
<td class="lst-td" style="border-top:1px solid #ccc" width="100%">
  <div>content</div>
</td>
```

**SPAN CSS**

```
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
border-bottom-color: black;
border-collapse: separate;
border-left-color: black;
border-right-color: black;
border-top-color: black;
color: black;
display: block;
float: right;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 23px;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 194px;
z-index: 5;
```

**SPAN HTML**

```
<span name="wrapSpan" class="wrapSpan" id="wrapSpan" style="white-space:     
nowrap;">
Content here!
</span>
```

Basically I'd like the span to "sit" over the TD. Problem is right now it's cutting it off and displaying after it. How would I fix that?

They're positioned like so..

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <span>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could please show us where is positioned span inside your html?

Comment: Woops! edited. hopefully that's sufficient!

Comment: That's illegal HTML. A table row can't contain a span.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sit a span inside a tr like that. It's not valid html. I would do the following... (showing only the important css)

```
<tr>
    <td><span></span></td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
td {position: relative;}
span {position: absolute; top:0;left;0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you meant

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What about giving `position:relative;` to the td and `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;` to the span?